# Handshake Error when using cloudflare with Heroku and Cookiecutter Django

Tags: ssl, heroku, cloudflare, handshake, cookiecutter-django

so I have a cookiecutter Django app on deployed on Heroku. Now I want to use cloudlfare to connect my custom domain to it. I set up the cloudflare cname records accordingly like explained here: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205893698-Configure-Cloudflare-and-Heroku-over-HTTPS

So both my cnames (one of my website name and one of called www) are both pointing at my DNS target that I got from Heroku when I added my domain.

Now what I get is an 525 ssl Handshake Error.

My question now is the following: I know that cookiecutter django forces ssl. Could that be the problem? Or could it be that I need to activate ssl on my hosting domain? (The problem with that is that my hoster tells me I can't get a ssl certificate when using another namespace, which I do, since I use cloudflare.)

Or what else could be the problem... I am a bit out of options....

Thanks in advance for your help....

Comment: I think this can solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52696794/1790381

Comment: In the meantime I could solve my problem. But yes, it was exactly what your link is suggesting: "Use the app URL (appname.herokuapp.com) as CNAME value instead of the domain generated by Heroku." Like that it worked perfectly. Thank you Minh for your help, very much appreciated